# $f,g$ be of bounded variation $\Rightarrow$ $f\circ g$ is of bounded variation?

Tags: bounded-variation

$f,g$ be of bounded variation $\Rightarrow$ $f \circ g$ is of bounded variation?

if not, any counter example?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the sign function, $f(x) = -1$ if $x\leq 0$, $f(x) = 1$ if $x>0$, and let
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} \chi_{[n, n+1)} (x),
$$
where $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function of the set $A$.

It is easily seen that $f, g\in BV(\mathbb{R})$, but
$$
(f\circ g)(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \chi_{[n, n+1)}(x)
$$
has not finite variation on $\mathbb{R}$.

If you prefer an example with continuous functions:
let us consider the functions $f,g \in C([0,1])$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{x},
\qquad
g(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2 \sin^2(1/x), &\text{if}\ x\in (0,1],\\
0, &\text{if}\ x = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
You can check that $f,g\in BV([0,1])$, but $f\circ g\not\in BV([0,1])$.

Comment: It also works with $g(x) = e^{-|x|}\sin(x)$, which seems easier to read and write. But good example nonetheless. It would also be interesting to explore what happens if we also require $f$ and $g$ to both be continuous. Can you make something continuous that still looks enough like $f$ to make the composition not have bounded variation?

Comment: Sure, it's enough to change sign countably many times. I have added an example with continuous functions.

Comment: how could I understand $g(x)$ is $BV(\Bbb R)$? and $TV$ of $f$ is $2$ right?

Comment: @delog The total variation of $g$ is $2\cdot\frac11+2\cdot\frac14+2\cdot\frac19+\cdots=\frac{\pi^2}3$.

Comment: @Arthur would you elaborate more the process to get the number 2 in front of each term?

Comment: It goes from $0$ to $\frac11$. Then it goes from $\frac11$ to $-\frac14$. Then it goes from $-\frac14$ to $\frac19$, and so on.